# Parse date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a date in the  format `16-2-2012`.

```
var k = getTomorrow('16-02-2012',1);
var myTime = k.getDate()+'-'+(k.getMonth()+1)+'-'+k.getFullYear();
```

Now I want to parse mytime to a date object. I have tried with

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
Date dtstr=parserSDF.parse(myTime);
```

But its not working. Is there any way around?

Comment: Why is that not working? what do you get?

Comment: Try DateFormat instead of SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Is this for java? Javascript? Or both!?

Comment: Sometimes the date format changes like to Thu Feb 23 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) then its showing errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dd-MM-yyyy` is the proper format - `M` means only one digit for the months

Comment: what if the format is Thu Feb 23 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: then you need a different date format. SimpleDateFormat documentation has a table that shows which is which.

Answer (score 0):

If variable myTime is String type then print it other wise convert it to String. if myTime = "16-03-2012" follow the format then you can use the code bellow.

```
try {
String myTime = "16-03-2012";
DateFormat formatter;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
date = (Date) formatter.parse(myTime);
System.out.println("Today is " + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
}
```

Comment: if the format is Thu Feb 23 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) then?